# Laravel uniqueness validation of hasMany

Tags: validation, laravel-8, unique, rules

I need to validate with the rule unique all code of the list of children before update, I know how to do it for the parent:

```
     $parent = Parent::find($id);
     $childrens = $parent->childrens;
     'code' => ['required', Rule::unique('parents', 'code')->ignore($parent->id)],        
     'childrens.*.code' => ['required', Rule::unique('childrens', 'code')],
```

There is any easy way to get the current IDs of children to ignore them like I did in the parent? Or any idea to allow update of the child?

Comment: `$parent->children()->pluck('id')` maybe? Kinda depends how/if you have a relationship between `parents` and `childrens`, or if you have a `$childrens` variable available, etc. Please consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74789432/edit) with more information, as we can only guess right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for hasMany relation in update is:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $childrens->count(); $i++) {
  $rules['childrens.' . $i . '.code'] = ['required', Rule::unique('childrens', 'code')->ignore($childrens[$i]['id'])];
}
```